# Insert multiple rows from one column in a table to the same column from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, so I have the following structure in my `product_to_store` table:

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| product_id - int(11) | store_id - int(11) |
+----------------------+--------------------+
+----------------------+--------------------+
| 1000                 | 0                  |
| 1000                 | 6                  |
| 1005                 | 0                  |
| 1010                 | 0                  |
| 1010                 | 6                  |
...
```

Basically, I need to have a `store_id` of value `6` for every `product_id`. For example, the product (`product_id`) with ID `1005` only has a `store_id` record of `0`. I want it to have another record/row where `product_id` is equal to `6`. Products with ID `1000` and `1010` are what they should be like (they have a record of `store_id` that is equal to `6`).

I tried to run the following query in order insert a new row where only `product_id` is set:

```
INSERT INTO `product_to_store` 
        (product_id) SELECT `product_id` 
                     FROM `product_to_store` 
                     WHERE product_id != 6
```

And then consider running another query to update all rows where `store_id` is `null` with the value of `6`. However, I get:

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '1000-0' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

Any way in which I can accomplish this without having to use a loop in PHP or something rather unpractical?

Comment: Please attach your schema. From the error it looks like `product_id` is primary key and won't allow you duplicate rows with same `product_id`

Comment: @e-neko this looks like a Cross Table between Products and stores so the unique key is probably the composite of Product_id & Store_Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `product_to_store` (product_id,store_id) 
SELECT DISTINCT p1.product_id, 6 as store_id
FROM
  product_to_store p1
  LEFT JOIN product_to_store x
  ON p1.product_id = x.product_id
  AND x.store_id = 6
WHERE
  x.product_id IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01ac7a

Comment: I tried that but it gives me  `#1062 - Duplicate entry '1005-6' for key 'PRIMARY'` as the query has already inserted such a row. I also tried copying the table to another table and then doing the SELECT on it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fine. I accepted the answer but sadly am unable to upvote it.

Comment: that's odd i got a duplicate entry when i try it in sqlfiddle

Comment: I can't because it's won't run so i can't give you the link but i can give you link to my answer and then you can just paste your answer in there.

Comment: @TinTran duhhh yep that is why the NOT EXISTS lol, but you still need to add DISTINCT to your answer!  I will change mine to be the LEFT JOIN method because it won't allow me to delete the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to insert products where there doesn't already exist a product with store_id of 6.

```
INSERT INTO `product_to_store` (product_id,store_id) 
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, 6 as store_id
FROM product_to_store p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_to_store p2 WHERE p2.store_id = 6
                  AND p2.product_id = p1.product_id)
```

Comment: I just got caught with this on my answer too but you will need DISTINCT because product_id can be represented more than 1 time in product_to_store.  But the next question why the not exists why not just where WHERE store_id !=6 seems like over complicating the issue...

Comment: DISTINCT won't work, because it'll try to add products (1000,6),(1005,6),(1010,6) but (1000,6),(1010,6) already exists so it fails on primary key.
NOT EXISTS will return just (1005,6) because there doesn't exists (1005,6) so it'll work

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de6737 here is a sql fiddle of your answer with DISTINCT in it, take out distinct and you will see it will fail because it tries to insert 1005 twice because I added (1005,1) as a row